# how to use tomcat7 as reactjs development server instead of nodejs express server?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, tomcat7

Hi I am working on a large scale application, front end is being developed in ReactJS, and back end would be in Java. For some reasons I want to use tomcat7 for both front end and back end. My question is can we use tomcat7 to debug and develop reactjs apps like nodejs express server?

Answer (score 0):

Java framework that you use, can serve a static file. All you have to do, build your react application and place it in a folder where your java application can actually serve them.

You don't have to create an instance of the express application to serve your frontend application.

I haven't worked on gradle, If your using maven as a build tool, you can use a plugin to build and place it under right folder when you build your java backend application

Comment: yes I know that process, but I want to use tomcat7 as development environment where I can debug the app just like nodejs express does.

Comment: 2 ways you can debug your application,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Create a folder in `webapp` tomcat
2. Copy your files from your local ReactJs build folder to this new folder.
3. Navigate to `'http://localhost:8080:<foldername>'`

These steps can be easily automated using build tool of your choice.

Edit - Make sure you copy `index.html` as well.

Comment: Hi Shaweta, Thanks for your reply but I have created the app through "npx create-react-app" and it does not create any index.html